# Absolute Path not detected in Open XML SDK

Tags: c#, spreadsheet, openxml-sdk

I am going crazy here. I cannot identify absolute paths in workbooks. The following code returns null on spreadsheets, which I can look in the xml (/xl/workbook.xml) has absolute path.

Can anybody please test the code and confirm if this is a bug ion Open XML SDK or my code?

XML qualified name is "x15ac:absPath".

Link to Open XML SDK info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.office2013.excelac.absolutepath?view=openxml-2.8.1

**Code**

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Office2013.ExcelAc;

public bool Check_AbsolutePath(string filepath)
{
    bool absolutepath = false;

    using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filepath, false))
    {
        if (spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AbsolutePath != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("--> Absolute path to local directory detected");
            absolutepath = true;
        }
    }
    return absolutepath;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I have created this as issue on Open XML SDK repo: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/issues/1208

Answer (score 0):

What you see is the expected result, because `AbsolutePath` is nullable. If you create a .xlsx file with Excel, the `AbsolutePath` property is not set by default.

Comment: Thx for your reply. I guarantee, that when I zip the spreadsheet and unpack it to access the xml files then workbook.xml has an absolute path value. Here's a [data sample package](https://github.com/Asbjoedt/CLISC/blob/master/Docs/SampleData.zip), pick any file they all have absolute paths.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I examined the xml of the several of the files from your link and none of them had an absolute path. Are you sure that's the right link?

Comment: I guarantee you I can see the absolute path and Excel can register it in the document insepction tool. [See screenshot though language is in Danish](https://i.postimg.cc/GhPVsdXd/Sk-rmbillede-2022-09-13-172655.png), but what it says is it has found an absolute path. Screenshot is from the file "Workbook_transitional.xlsx"

Can you possibly share an Excel .xlsx file with me, that you know has an absolute path. Then I can run this file through my program to debug what is happening better.

Comment: What tool are you using in the image to find the absolute url? According to the OOXML SDK, AbsolutePath represents the following element tag in the schema: `x15ac:absPath`. I searched the xml parts and this element is not there. Can you look at the xml directly and see if it has an `x15ac:absPath`. element? This vs code extension I work on can help you do that: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yuenm18.ooxml-viewer

Comment: I used Excel and its feature "Inspect document" for the screenshot. I have also opened several of the files in the data sample by unzipping them and looking at the workbook.xml file, and I see a filepath at "x15ac:absPath". Here is screenshot from your nice OOXML Viewer with abspath: https://ibb.co/55qvYR3

Comment: That's interesting, maybe zipping it has some effect. Can you put the docx from the zip file on your repo, but unzipped?

Comment: I am not interested in the .docx (I checked it using OOXML Viewer anyway and document.xml does not have absPath in that document). My program only handles spreadsheets, and I include the .docx just to make sure the program ignores it. All of the spreadsheets has an absolute path, but Open XML SDK won't report it. I now made an .xlsx in Excel, wrote "Hello CascadiaJS" and saved it to Desktop and this spreadsheet has absPath by default. I ran my program (which runs above code) and absPath did not register. [I share file](https://github.com/Asbjoedt/CLISC/blob/master/Docs/Mappe1.xlsx)

Comment: I am seeing the `x15ac:absPath` element now. I'm not sure why I didn't see it before. This definitely looks like a bug, you should file it on the [OOXML SDK issues page](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/issues)

Comment: Thanks mate. I registered it as an issue: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/issues/1208